# Swapping product images for custom lists using a new image attribute

Tags: image, category

I want to be able to display a list of products on the homepage of the site I am working on with a different image to what is displayed on the category page.

I have created a new image attribute called 'featured_image' and have set a number of featured products with images filled in however the modified template I am using for the homepage is only showing the placeholder images for this new image type and I am at a loss to why.

The code I am using for my featured home page block is

```
<?php if($_collectionSize > 0): ?>
<ul class="products-grid">
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <li class="<?php if($i-1==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i==$_collectionSize): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'featured_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'featured_image')->resize(250); ?>" width="250" height="250" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'featured_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php if($i==$_limit): break; endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Many thanks, I'm sure this is something simple I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by that the attribute is not included in the product listing collection. Therefore the field is not accessible and gives a NULL or empty string.

As there is no option to change this value after you selected the Media Image value you need to change this in the catalog_eav_attribute table (column used_in_product_listing).

When you create a new attribute and set the option 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' to Yes before you change the type to Media Image and then save it is also works as the value is then saved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I had missed that when setting up the new attribute. I removed and re-added the attribute and its working just as I had hoped!